# Accuracy on training set is weirdly low compared to validation accuracy for many classifiers. Is this normal?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data

I thought that after fitting data, and predicting the training set, you should get an accuracy that is close to 100%. I mean that only makes sense. The algorithm learns based on that dataset. But when i do:

```py
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

print(accuracy_score(y_test, pred))

>>> 0.810126582278481
```

This is fine. However, if I do:

```py
pred = classifier.predict(X_train)

print(accuracy_score(y_train, pred))

>>> 0.6677316293929713
```

Isn't this kind of a fallacy? Or am I doing something wrong...? This applies to RandomForestClassifier, MLPClassifier and SVC.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211184/10981911) answer explains this behaviour well. You have a regularization term (or "penality" parameter) `C` which defaults to a value of 1; this prevents over-fitting and explains the low accuracy. Try increasing the value of the parameter `C` by doing the following:

```py
classifier = svm.SVC(C=200000)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = classifier.predict(X_train)
print(accuracy_score(y_train, pred))
```

Comment: @Snusifer considering accepting this as the correct answer if this helped :)